# Cordova - image from library returning extension (.pic.jpg) before the name

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

Im trying to get the path and file name of an image from library, but it`s returning the extension (.pic.jpg) before name like:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/cache/.Pic.jpg.filename

When I get the image from camera, it`s work normally.

my code:

```
    function getPhoto() {
          // Retrieve image file location from specified source
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { 
             quality: 25, 
             allowEdit: true, 
             correctOrientation: true,
             destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
             encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
             sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, });
        }
```

Comment: I have the same problem did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a picture from the library the file is saved on cache folder with name ".Pic.jpg" but another information (numbers) is placed after the filename, like this: "?1500664367002". Now I don't know what means this number, but you can copy, upload or show the picture from this address (file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/cache/.Pic.jpg).